# hubot-slack throwing an error on startup

Tags: node.js, hubot, slack

I am trying to add a new hubot integration to our Slack channels. I am setting this up on a Windows machine and am deploying to a Heroku server. I followed the installation instructions provided here: https://github.com/slackhq/hubot-slack

I can create and run a new hubot instance on my local computer (calling "bin/hubot" in a Powershell prompt), but when I install the hubot-slack package and add "hubot-slack" to the external-scripts file I get an error. If I remove the value from the external-scripts file everything is fine.

```
PS C:\hubot> bin/hubot
jarvis> [Tue Dec 22 2015 15:18:24 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)] ERROR Error loading scripts from npm package - TypeError: require(...) is not a function
  at Robot.loadExternalScripts (C:\hubot\node_modules\hubot\src\robot.coffee:399:11)
  at C:\hubot\node_modules\hubot\bin\hubot:128:26
  at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)
```

If I include the adapter flag for Slack I get a different error. I tried setting HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN as a System Environment variable.

```
PS C:\hubot> bin/hubot -a slack
[Tue Dec 22 2015 15:21:54 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)] ERROR No services token provided to Hubot
```

Every example I can find is including the HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN in the call to hubot, but it doesn't work for me (I must be missing something).

```
PS C:\hubot> HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN=xoxb-22211110000-123456781234ZZZZYYYYXXXX ./bin/hubot --adapter slack
HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN=xoxb-17240119159-dBeAEc2X8M2O9vJBYzWj5KFW : The term
'HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN=xoxb-17240119159-dBeAEc2X8M2O9vJBYzWj5KFW' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN=xoxb-22211110000-123456781234ZZZZYYYYXXXX ./bin/hubot --adapte ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HUBOT_SLACK_TOK...234ZZZZYYYYXXXX:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

To rule out something locally I deployed the application to Heroku, but I got a different error.

```
2015-12-22T22:28:49.426496+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-12-22T22:14:54.739959+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-12-22T22:14:55.133113+00:00 app[web.1]: [Tue Dec 22 2015 22:14:55 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Error loading scripts from npm package - TypeError: object is not a function
2015-12-22T22:14:55.133117+00:00 app[web.1]:   at Robot.loadExternalScripts (/app/node_modules/hubot/src/robot.coffee:399:11, <js>:269:39)
2015-12-22T22:14:55.133119+00:00 app[web.1]:   at fs.js:272:14
2015-12-22T22:14:55.133121+00:00 app[web.1]:   at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
2015-12-22T22:14:56.115333+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "jarvis",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "author": "Me <email@domain.com>",
  "description": "A friendly robot",
  "dependencies": {
    "hubot": "^2.17.0",
    "hubot-diagnostics": "0.0.1",
    "hubot-google-images": "^0.2.6",
    "hubot-google-translate": "^0.2.0",
    "hubot-help": "^0.1.2",
    "hubot-heroku-keepalive": "^1.0.1",
    "hubot-maps": "0.0.2",
    "hubot-pugme": "^0.1.0",
    "hubot-redis-brain": "0.0.3",
    "hubot-rules": "^0.1.1",
    "hubot-scripts": "^2.16.2",
    "hubot-shipit": "^0.2.0",
    "requirejs": "^2.1.22",
    "hubot-slack": "^3.4.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x"
  }
}
```

external-scripts.json

```
[
  "hubot-diagnostics",
  "hubot-help",
  "hubot-heroku-keepalive",
  "hubot-google-images",
  "hubot-google-translate",
  "hubot-pugme",
  "hubot-maps",
  "hubot-redis-brain",
  "hubot-rules",
  "hubot-shipit",
  "requirejs",
  "hubot-slack"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, it seems that the mechanism is a little different from what it processes in Linux. The error 'HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN is not recognized' is raised because it would read the value of 'HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN' from environment variables in windows.

**Create an environment variable** 'HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN' manually and set the value, it will work.

You could check it out in the source code in the github repo: slack.coffee.

```
options =
  token: process.env.HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN
  autoReconnect: !exitProcessOnDisconnect
  autoMark: true
  exitOnDisconnect: exitProcessOnDisconnect
  proxyUrl: process.env.https_proxy
```

Comment: `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN","xoxb-22211110000-123456781234ZZZZYYYYXXXX")` worked for me.  Or `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN","xoxb-22211110000-123456781234ZZZZYYYYXXXX", "Machine")` if it's running under a service account.

Answer (score 0):

What intrigues me is this particular line:

```
Error loading scripts from npm package - TypeError: require(...) is not a function
```

Did you add the other scripts from the repo aswell?

There also might be something wrong with the node/npm/coffee installation/version on your windows machine. Make sure that those are installed and in a compatible version. Another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33858433/1309035) had an issue with incompatible versions. Please tell us about the versions you use and try downgrading node to 0.12.x.

The way you use the token is fine.

Comment: I uninstalled node.js and reinstalled node v0.12.7, npm v2.11.3, coffee v1.10.0.  Now when I try to run bin\hubot I get ERROR Error loading scripts from npm package - TypeError: object is not a function at Robot.loadExternalScripts (C:\hubot\node_modules\hubot\src\robot.coffee:399:11) at C:\hubot\node_modules\hubot\bin\hubot:128:26 at fs.js:334:14 at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)

Comment: It turns out the issue was caused because I included hubot-slack in my external-scripts.json file. After I removed it, I was able to run hubot. https://github.com/slackhq/hubot-slack/issues/197

Comment: Please put that up as the answer if it solved your question. And maybe explain a bit why ;)