# TypeError: require(...) is not a function in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get, socket.io

I am trying to learn node js and trying few sample code, and when I come across the socket.io website, I tried the sample code in their website. I don't think the code written on their website will be wrong. The error which I'm getting while I'm running the code, I don't know how to solve it, I don't know where I have done wrong. I'm very new to node js, please help me. This is the link of
[website](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)
 which I taken the code.

And this is code which I'm trying to run.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('listening on *:3000');
 });
```

And the error I'm getting while running the code is

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);                                                                                                               
                         ^                    
TypeError: require(...) is not a function                                                                                                          
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/index.js:3:30)                                                                                   
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)                                                                                                          
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)                                                                                            
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)                                                                                                              
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)                                                                                                    
at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:475:10)                                                                                           
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:89:15)
```

Comment: You need to install the package with `npm`. Did you install?

Comment: Yeah, I have installed.

Comment: what's the node version? check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33858433/1398867

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like @venogopal said, the issue might be the version of `socket.io`:

for `0.9.x`:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

for `1.x.x`:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
```